# How to append GET parameter for every URL request from a browser?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

For testing, I need to append "**?testing=true**" for every URL reference in my webpage. 
For example, say webpage has an image "***localhost/image/logo.png***" I need to this should be converted to "***localhost/image/logo.png?testing=true***" when loaded on a browser.

I tried several plugins on firefox, which allows appending/modifying URL on submit, but my requirement is to change URL on load.

Comment: What does it mean to "change URL on load" and why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have local server configuration to block all hits except from test server. But it wont block any url if its url has "?testing=true". 
I cant change any of server settings or OS settings. Only control i have is how i load URL. If i load "http://localhost" it will be blocked, if i load "http://localhost?testing=true" it will open.
Problem with this is, index.html has image refs (which will be blocked)

Comment: On a personal note I find it quite strange that you can't change the server configuration on localhost, but anyway ... knowing what you want to achieve in the end might help answering your question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some success with the Firefox Greasemonkey extension. You can use a script like this:

```
var parameter = '?testing=true'
for (var x = 0; x < document.images.length; x++) {
    image = docuent.images[x];
    image.src = image.src + parameter;
    console.log(image.src);
}
for (x = 0; x < document.getElementsByTagName("link").length; x++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("link")[x].href = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[x].href + parameter;
}
```

It replaces all embedded images and stylesheets with the same files with "?testing=true" appended. However there are still requests to the original image before that.

Another option would be to use a local proxy such as Charles for URL rewriting.

Comment: Great!... it works for Images. But It is failing to load CSS (localhost/css/test.css). Is there any way to append parameter for any external reference URl too?